# cross compiling VIM

Tags: c, gcc, vim, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile the vim for ARM. i changed the cross compiler gcc path in make file and rum the make command in vim74/src directory. but it gives me linker error.

Where i can get the path lib for this cross platform ?

```
error:
<arm>/arm-2012.03/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: library search path "/usr/local/lib" is unsafe for cross-compilation
 <path>/arm-2012.03/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk-x11-2.0
<path>/arm-2012.03/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk-x11-2.0
<path>/arm-2012.03/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
<path>/arm-2012.03/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
<path>/arm-2012.03/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangoft2-1.0
<path>/arm-2012.03/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0
<path>/arm-2012.03/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
```

Comment: removed the c++ tag, since vim is pure C, and added the cross-compiling tag. You don't really tell us anything about your cross-compilation toolchain or the system that you're doing this on. With as little information as this, chances are really really slim you'll get help.

Comment: Also, adding back "any help is appreciated" *decreases* the quality of your question, so I recommend leaving it out (it's just chatter).

Comment: yes. i am trying to cross compile the software for ARM. software may have linked with some linux system libraries. by default the library is compiled for host platform. target platform is different from host. i need those libraries compiled for target too.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to compile the VIM for ARM platform. i have downloaded the VIM source code and changed the gcc path for cross compiler. VIM is getting compiled for ARM but it is failing against to link some libraries. i know default system library can not be linked. i need same libraries which is compiled for ARM platform. i don't know where i can get this library path.  someone have compiled it for cross platform .. how ?? how he had provided the those library.... where i can get ???